# Amazon SMS delivery status and incoming SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I'm working on Amazon SMS and I want to get SMS delivery status on my project API(EndPoint) because i can't find the reason why SMS getting failed  and also configure opt-out system so suggest me how to configure this system

[image]

Comment: Rather than trying to build this type of system yourself, you might consider using [Amazon Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/welcome.html). It includes the ability to [opt out of SMS messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-manage.html).

Comment: Ok, so we required any Long Code or Short Code for inbound(incoming) message?

Comment: And I want sent SMS from c# Server side I don't want to make any Segment and  Campaigns because Message body and Mobile number frequently change based on conditions so Is it possible in Amazon pinpoint.